# Why compilation allowed when expected is return type mismatch?

Tags: java

```
int fun(){
return (true?null:0);
}
```

Here clearly null is not of int type which is allowed to be returned and compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapper class of it. For ex

```
Integer integ = null;
```

You are allowed to do

```
int fun(){
return (true?integ:0);
}
```

Autoboxing and unboxing. But when you run that code, you are going to face NPE since the run time try to convert the null Integer to it's corresponding primitive.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will throw a NullPointerException when called.

Comment: @user1675642 it's just allowed to do. Not to run successfully.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mismatched type here. Your example can be simplified to

```
public int foo()
{
    return true ? 0 : null;
}
```

The ternary will auto-box the 0 to an `Integer` type which gets auto-unboxed back to an `int`. Since an `Integer` can also be `null`, both expressions in the ternary then have the same type.

The `null` branch will throw a NullPointerException. See for yourself by changing `true` to `false` in my example

In my opinion this is one of the flaws in Java that emanates from the retention of the plain old data types, and the type promotion rules in a ternary are particularly pernicious.

Comment: `null` won't be auto-boxed, it is just a value by definition assignable to any reference type.

Comment: Indeed. Corrected my sloppy language.

Comment: Sorry for being overly pedantic, I just wanted to help cos I've seen people downvoted for less. :)

Comment: Not at all. Precision is very important in this field.